# How to implement my own locking mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, locking

For an assignment (it's for concurrency if you wonder) - I have to implement my own lock

**(more specific: a TaS, a TTas and an Array-Lock, as described in "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming")**

There are some test in- and output schemes online that I tried (too bad they take pretty long to try).

> Your program is to count 9-digit numbers that pass a certain test

**(it's called the elfproef in dutch, I don't know the english equivalence, sorry).**

Sometimes I got a slightly different number, which suggests that my lock doesn't work a *100% right*.

I have implemented the locks like this:

```
interface Lock
{
    void Lock();
    void Unlock();
}

class TaSLock : Lock
{
    AtomicBool state = new AtomicBool(false);

    void Lock.Lock()
    { while (state.getAndSet(true)); }

    void Lock.Unlock()
    { state.getAndSet(false); }
}
```

The `AtomicBool` is implemented with an `integer`, because the `Interlocked` class doesn't have operations for `Boolean` variables. This isn't optimal in terms of memory usage but it doesn't (or shouldn't) matter for the speed.

```
class AtomicBool
{
    int value;
    static int True = 1, False = -1;

    public AtomicBool(bool value)
    {
        if (value) this.value = True;
        else this.value = False;
    }

    public void set(bool newValue)
    {
        if (newValue) Interlocked.Exchange(ref value, True);
        else Interlocked.Exchange(ref value, False);
    }

    public bool getAndSet(bool newValue)
    {
        int oldValue;
        if (newValue) oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref value, True);
        else oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref value, False);
        return (oldValue == True);
    }

    public bool get()
    {
        return (Interlocked.Add(ref value, 0) == 1);
    }
}
```

Now in the parallel part I have just used:

```
theLock.Lock();
counter++;
theLock.Unlock();
```

But each time I get slightly different results.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may also benefit from codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @0a0d Since this is about an actual problem it's not a review question.

Comment: This can only work on a single core CPU.  You are missing the memory barrier that ensures all cores have an up-to-date view of memory.  Atomicity is not enough.  How old is the book?

Comment: @HansPassant: Amazon says it was published in 2008. http://www.amazon.com/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Maurice-Herlihy/dp/0123705916

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hans is right. Your atomic get-and-set boolean appears to be correct -- in fact, it appears to me to be somewhat over-engineered. And the lock appears to be *correct* as well, insofar as you've built yourself a potentially highly inefficient "spin lock". (That is, all the waiting threads just sit there in a tight loop asking "can I go yet? can I go yet?" instead of going to sleep until it is their turn.)

What is not correct is that your lock provides no guarantee whatsoever that any two threads that both have a view of "counter" have a *consistent* view of "counter". Two threads could be on different processors, and those different processors could have different copies of "counter" in their caches. The cached copies will be updated, and only occasionally written back to main memory, thereby effectively "losing" some increases.

The real implementation of locking in C# ensures that a full-fence memory barrier is imposed so that reads and writes cannot move "forwards and backwards in time" across the fence. That gives a hint to the processors that they need to not be so smart about caching "counter" so aggressively.

Comment: I'm not sure if our implementation has to use spin locks, but it's the way it was mentioned in the book. Thanks for your answer, anyway! I understand the assignment a bit better now. I think I should look up a bit more about the memory barries and find a way to efficiently divide the range over the threads.

Comment: @user969527: While you are at it, take a look at the bit in the C# specification that describes the semantics of "volatile" and the guarantees about the execution order of critical points like thread starts, locks, and so on. That should help you get this right. This brief overview I wrote might also help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Comment: @user969527: Vance Morrison's article might also be of help to you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx